# Prove the following or provide a counter-example if the claim is false.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

log5(2) ∈ I. Hint: Consider using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.

Comment: Did you try something? and first of all don't give your questions as a command you state what you did and what you can't do.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $\log_{5}2 = \dfrac{m}{n} \Rightarrow 2^n = 5^m$. One number is odd and the other is even, how can they be equal?